# Study the continuity domain and derivability domain

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Let $(u_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ with the general term $u_n=\frac {1+x^{n}}{1+x+x^{2}+...+x^{n+p-1}}$, where $x\ge0$ and $p \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $f(x)= \lim_{n\to\infty}u_n$. Find the differentiability and continuity domain.

First I tried to simplify a little $u_n$ using the sum of the geometric progression and I got this
$$u_n=\frac{(1+x^{n})(x-1)}{x^{n+p}-1}.$$
So if $x \in (0,1)$, then $f(x)=1-x$.

What should I do when $x = 1$ and $x>1$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I think you have a slight error in you the sum of a geometric progression formula: the denominator must be $x^{n+p}-1$, not $x^{n+p\color{red}{-1}}-1$.

If $x=1$, you can literally plug it into the original expression for $u_n$.

If $x>1$, then the let's divide the numerator and denominator by $x^n$:
$$u_n=\frac{(1+x^n)(x-1)}{x^{n+p}-1}=\frac{\left(\frac{1}{x^n}+1\right)(x-1)}{x^p-\frac{1}{x^n}},$$
and observe that in this case $1/x^n\to0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: oh, you're right

Comment: If I plug in 1 in the original expression doesn't it interfere some errors? $\frac 00$?

Comment: @C.Cristi: Not into the simplified, but into the original: $u_n(x)=\frac{1+x^n}{1+x+x^2+...+x^{n+p-1}}$, so $u_n(1)=\cdots$.

Comment: Yeah, right. If I'm right $u_n(1)=0$?

Comment: @C.Cristi: yes.

Comment: So the answer to the original question, *the domain of differentiability and continuity* is  the entire domain of definition of $f(x)$ and in this case if D= domain of differentiability and C = domain of continuity then: $D = C = [0,+\infty)$?

Comment: Additional question: If a function is not continue in a point $x_0$ then can that function be differentiable in that point $x_0$?

Comment: @C.Cristi: To answer your additional question: no. There's a theorem that says that if a function is differentiable at a point $x_0$, then the function is continuous at that point. Therefore, as a corollary, not being continuous implies not being differentiable (at a point).

Comment: @C.Cristi: As for the original question: the two domains are not the same for this function. It's correct that $C=[0,+\infty)$, but $D$ isn't exactly the same. Hint: is this function differentiable at $x=1$?

Comment: Yeah, I should've differentiate it first, it isn't differentiable at x = 1. Thank you !